# Probability of throwing darts when likelyhood of hitting one side is more than the other

Tags: probability

Currently learning probability from MIT OCW 6.041. I want to understand the following regarding **Problem #5** from the [PSET1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn01.pdf)(read the question here at MIT OCW). I am unable to understand part **c** of the given problem.

We need to calculate the probability of John hitting 50 point mark on the dartboard. I understand that we are looking for values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are the proportionality constants, I want to understand **why the probability of throwing the dart in the right half of the board is $\frac{2}{3}$**

The question being asked above(in bold) is being referenced from the answer given for the **Problem #5** referenced from the solution of the [PSET1-Solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn01_sol.pdf) from the MIT OCW site.

> The  first  term  in  the  sum  is  proportional  to  the  area  of  the  right  half  of  the  inner  disk and  is  equal  to απR2/2 = απ/2, where α is  a  constant  to  be  determined. Similarly,  the  probability  of  him  throwing  in  the  left  half  of  the  board  and  scoring  50 points  is  equal  to βπ/2, where β is  a  constant (not  necessarily  equal  to α). ***In  order  to  determine α and β,  let  us  compute  the  probability  of  throwing  the  dart  in the  right  half  of  the  board.  This  probability  is  equal  to απR2/2 = απ102/2 = α50π.
> Since  that  probability  is  equal  to  2/3***, α = 1/(75π). In  a  similar  fashion, β can  be determined  to  be  1/(150π).   Consequently,  the  total  probability  is  equal  to  1/150  + 1/300  = 0.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to understand **why the probability of throwing the dart in the
> right half of the board is $\frac{2}{3}$**

We are told that "John is right handed and is twice more likely to throw in the right half of the board than in the left half."

So, $P(\text{Right half of the board}) = 2P(\text{Left half of the board})$.

Since there are only two sides of the board, $$P(\text{Right half of the board}) + P(\text{Left half of the board}) = 1 = P(\text{hit on the board})$$ $$\text{(we're gonna assume missing the board is impossible)}$$

Substituting in our first equation,

$$2P(\text{Left half of the board}) + P(\text{Left half of the board}) = 1$$
$$3P(\text{Left half of the board}) = 1$$
$$P(\text{Left half of the board}) = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$P(\text{Right half of the board}) = 2P(\text{Left half of the board}) = \frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since John is twice as likely to hit the right part of the board, for every one dart that he lands on the left half, he would have landed two darts on the right half.

Thus out of every 3 darts thrown, two land on the right half and one lands on the left half. Thus $\alpha = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\beta = \frac{1}{3}$.